# is there any similar treegrid similar to jqGrid Treegrid but supports frozen columns

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid

I like [using jqGrid treegrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atreegrid) but there is one feature that i absolutely need which is frozen columns.  Is there any similar quality product that supports frozen columns.  I know that jqgrid supports frozen columns in the regular grid (but not the tree grid)

Comment: Please make your question more explicit by stating what you want in terms of functionality rather than comparing it to a specific part of a plugin. It is not clear to me what you need; hard to provide a solution to an unknown problem. It will also help to explain the options you have looked in and why they didn't work so others benefit from your work as well. – Adriaan

Comment: @Adriaan - i am not sure that anything more explicit is needed.  I need a treegrid which by itself is pretty self explanatory.  I referenced jqGrid Treegrid as an example of a treegrid that i use and like today (no real value listing every features of jqGrid Treegrid but i added a link to the feature page) and i highlighted one missing feature which is frozen columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box solution, but you could try [slickGrid](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html)

Unfortunately it doesn't provide fixed columns functionality (yet), but there is fork, that has frozen columns you can [use](http://github.com/JLynch7/SlickGrid/tree/2.0-frozenRowsAndColumns)

**UPDATE**

You may also take look at [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/treegrid2.php) -

[Sample](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/treegrid2_demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

[DHTMLX treegrid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/index.shtml) supports frozen columns.

See this [demo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTreeGrid/samples/07_split/01_treeGrid_split.html)

Answer (score 0):

If time is not a constraint and you can waste a little in R&D, [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) here can help you.
Plus If you really have enough time, go through this nice article about [7 Best grid plugins](http://www.queness.com/post/7300/7-robust-and-feature-packed-javascript-grid-plugins).

Hope it helps,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is a tree Grid in [extended js](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel)

its an easy way to integrated fast

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.htmltreegrid.com/) one supports left and right locked columns:

Answer (score 0):

Frozen Columns are supported in the jQWidgets TreeGrid, too. Example: [TreeGrid Frozen Columns](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/javascript-tree-grid-pinned-column.htm?arctic)

Answer (score -1):

jqGrid 4.3 should support column freezing (according to the [release notes](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=874))

Newest release 4.3.1 [see trirand.com blog](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=883)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't support frozen columns for the treegrid